# Modify DOM outside React App without reconciliation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, virtual-dom

I have a React app embedded in an external .Net app. all works fine, but I have a plugin on the main app to translate the content of entire content including the content inside the React App which is a problem because the real Dom can't conciliate Virtual Dom the when the change is produced. I don't really want to sync Virtual Dom with the Real DOM changed because some of those texts are part of the react app state.

Any valid approach that I can't use to update those text without affecting the React App?

Comment: if your plugin uses google translate try adding `translate="no"` to your root element `<html translate="no">` or `<div id="app" translate="no">`

Comment: The best thing would to translate the React app seperately. But if that's not an options, then the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) would be an alternative.